# One domain name, two locations, depending on login information

Tags: domain, login, website, privacy, country

We have 2 identical websites located in 2 different countries on two different subdomains in the same domain name, i.e. "us.site.com" and "ca.site.com". It is setup this way due to privacy laws that require the data be stored in the country it belongs to. We want to have a single domain name for users to login to like [www.site.com](http://www.site.com). We want to keep the 2 locations separated. Is this possible?

More details:
After the user has logged in, we want the domain name to appear as "www.site.com" even though the user's session is being hosted in "us.site.com" (USA) or "ca.site.com" (Canada) depending on their username. I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: usually yes. depending on the use case you planned. but you did not give us enough information. so we can only speculate

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are correct. each subdomain is counted as a single domain and could be set up on different servers and different countries. The NameServer here is just doing the name resolution to point the request towards the requested subdomain.